# compiled bash script with docker produces indecipherable output

Tags: docker, compilation

I want to compile bash script using the shc docker image

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
```

Docker image building

```
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM shc
 ---> df064ace9db8
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2af32576943
Successfully built b2af32576943
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Compiling

```
$ docker run \
    --rm \
    -v "$PWD:/shc-data" \
    test \
    shc -f /shc-data/script
```

Test

```
$ ./script.x
./script.x: ��J��X+QV6+��矕v���
```

Why  script produces indecipherable output?